# Spacing elements covered by fixed navbar

Tags: html, css

I often have this problem with a lot of fixed navbars i.e. when I have a fixed navbar, how do I give the element below it some margin, so that the fixed navbar is not covering that element?

I was just wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this apart from the `<br>` tag and `margin-top`.

The sample code would be like:

HTML code :

```
    <nav>
        I AM NAVBAR
    </nav>
    <br><br>
    <div>

    </div>
```

CSS code :

```
* {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            nav {
                height: 50px;
                width: 100%;
                background: #444;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family: verdana;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            div {
                height: 500px;
                width: 100%;
                background: tomato;
            }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5k5mxcn1/) here.

Comment: No need for ugly break tags, nothing wrong with some margin - and it should do the trick. Not exactly sure what the issue is here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed position relatives to the screen's viewport. You can just set top margin or padding on the body tag, and make the value >= the navbar height.

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px; /*or padding*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5k5mxcn1/1/

Answer (score 1):

There's a theory in CSS that you only apply bottom margins.
http://csswizardry.com/2012/06/single-direction-margin-declarations/

So to keep things modular, you could create a wrapping class:

```
<nav class="nav__wrapper">
    <div class="nav__content">
        Navigation
    </div>
</nav>

<p>Text content</p>
```

css:

```
.nav__wrapper {
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px // breathing room
}

.nav__content {
    background: #dadada;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wv53qLwz/

Answer (score 0):

A fixed element is position relative to the viewport, meaning it stays at the same designate spot and does not leave a gap in the page where it would normally have been located.
You can apply a top margin to the element that is directly following the fixed element.

```
div {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

However, I've found out that using the scroll-margin property does the trick. It's explained better here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-margin/#aa-enter-scroll-margin

```
div {
   scroll-margin-top: 50px;
}
```